# getAdGroupBidLandscape returning no campaigns found

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to use the Google AdWords bid simulator system to try and get some insights out of the AdWords bid simulator. More specifically I'm using the AdGroupBidLandscape() functionality, but it's returning 'No Campaigns Found', but we definitely have campaigns where the Bid Simulator tool works through the AdWords web page interface, so I'm a bit confused.  Here is the code I'm running, and yes I know I'm only retrieving a single field - I'm just trying to keep things as simple as possible.

```
from googleads import adwords
import logging
import time
CHUNK_SIZE = 16 * 1024
PAGE_SIZE = 100
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
dataService = adwords_client.GetService('DataService', version='v201710')
offset = 0
selector = {'fields':['Bid'], #'impressions', 'promotedImpressions', 'requiredBudget', 'bidModifier', 'totalLocalImpressions', 'totalLocalClicks', 'totalLocalCost', 'totalLocalPromotedImpressions'],
'paging': {
        'startIndex': str(offset),
        'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
    }
}

more_pages = True
while more_pages:
  page = dataService.getAdGroupBidLandscape(selector)
  # Display results.
  if 'entries' in page:
    for campaign in page['entries']:
      print ('Campaign with id "%s", name "%s", and status "%s" was '
             'found.' % (campaign['id'], campaign['name'],
                         campaign['status']))
  else:
    print 'No campaigns were found.'
  offset += PAGE_SIZE
  selector['paging']['startIndex'] = str(offset)
  more_pages = offset < int(page['totalNumEntries'])
  time.sleep(1)
```

We have several different accounts attachd to AdWords.  My account is the only one that has developer API access, so I sort of wonder if the problem is that my account isn't the primary account associated with the campaigns- I just have one of the few administrator accounts.  Can anyone provide some insights about this for me?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to add a predicate to the selector specifying a particular CampaignId. While that doesn't make any sense to me that it would fix it, because it should really just be filtering the data with that if I understand things correctly, it seems to have.  I don't have a good explanation for that, but I thought someone else might find this useful.  If I come to realize this wasn't the fix to the problem I had, I will come back and update this answer.